# How to handle window keydown event when it contain previewkeydown event of textbox?

Tags: wpf, keydown

My application have custom image control,button and a custom textbox.I implemented some key operations in window keydown event belonging to image and some key operations in textbox previewkeydown event.When the focus is on image or button,key operations of the window works well.When the focus is on the textbox,combination of two key operations doesn't work well.For example,when the focus is on textbox,if I pressed ctrl + up arrow,first it fires the keydown event of both textbox and window keydown event where e.key contain ctrl.second textbox's keydown event is fired but windows keydown event is not fired why..?

Answer (score 0):

Might input binding help you out?

See: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands

Its what's used for keyboard input in WPF way more than the KeyDown and KeyUp events.  I'm having my own issues with those right now, ugh.